# New programmer C# - How to add multiple numericUpDown values?

Tags: c#

I am making a program which needs to add the value of all numericUpDowns, and display it on the label.

numericUpDowns are created programatically and added to ArrayList.

```
ArrayList numericUpDownMy = new ArrayList();
     numericUpDownMy.Add(new NumericUpDown());
        System.Drawing.Point h = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 275+ i * 19);          
        (numericUpDownMy[i] as NumericUpDown).Location = h;
        (numericUpDownMy[i] as NumericUpDown).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(numericUpDownMy[i] as NumericUpDown);
         int total = (((int)numericUpDown[0]) + ((int)numericUpDown[1]) + ((int)numericUpDown[2]) + ((int)numericUpDown[3]));
    labelScore.Text = total.ToString();
```

Obviously this doesn't work as I don't get the actual value of NumericUpDown. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no reason to be using `ArrayList` -- look at generic Lists instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line :

```
  decimal total = (numericUpDownMy[1] as NumericUpDown).Value + 
                  (numericUpDownMy[2] as NumericUpDown).Value + 
                  (numericUpDownMy[3] as NumericUpDown).Value;
```

and besides that don't use `ArrayList`, use  `List<NumericUpDown>`, to get rid of all that casting or add to collection at the end. I would wrote that code in this way :

```
  List<NumericUpDown> numUpDnList = new List<NumericUpDown>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    NumericUpDown numUpDn = new NumericUpDown();
    numUpDn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 275 + i * 19);
    numUpDn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(numUpDn);
    numUpDnList.Add(numUpDn);
  }
  decimal total = numUpDnList.Sum(updn => updn.Value);
  labelScore.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if add it under button_click event, but how would I make this updated all time on value change in numericUpDownMy .

Comment: You should declare list of NumericUpDown as a private member of form, and on NumericUpDown ValueChanged event sum all in that list, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this but I still get error: Error creating window handle
on line:

                    this.Controls.Add(numUpDn);

Comment: where do you adding controls ? Do that in form Load event

Comment: under button_click event, because depending on user choice it creates 2,3 or 4 NumericUpDowns

Comment: Well, if you are doin it once it should be OK, if not you have to think that you allready have some num edits. But please post some code in question becouse it's not clear why you get this error